# Assessing role of a count variable in regression... Do you need a zero?

Tags: regression, logistic

Is it acceptable to run a logistic regression on a yes/no DV and include a predictor variable that is a count of the number of times something happened previously, but none of the cases has a zero count? It seems to me you would be testing if more than 1 event matters, but not whether the overall number matters compared to no events.

Thanks.

To give some context, it's a study to see how interaction with government officials affects future use of government services. If the participants were limited to those who had at least one interaction, could you then use a regression to identify the potential effect of each additional interaction? It would seem to be a better design and more robust results if you had some "zero" participants too. Thoughts?

Thanks for the thoughtful responses. It's not my study, I'm assessing someone else's. It just struck me as odd to talk about the effect of something without including the comparison of people who had no experience with X. It may not be the number of times something happened that creates the effect, but rather that it happened at all. you may detect an intensification of the effect with more of X, but without zero, do you know if it would hold if there was no X. And, yes, there are many other issues, as it's apparent the number of previous X is definitely not random. Thanks again

Comment: There are no technical problems with obtaining the results of that regression, Chris, but it sounds like you may be asking about how to interpret them and the extent to which they can be trusted. I can imagine situations where this would give me some misgivings and others where it would be perfectly fine. Could you help us understand you better by disclosing a little more information about this predictor variable and how it might be related to the DV?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. To give some context, it's a study to see how interaction with government officials affects future use of government services. If the participants were limited to those who had at least one interaction, could you then use a regression to identify the potential effect of each additional interaction? It would seem to be a better design and more robust results if you had some "zero" participants too. Thoughts?

Comment: If the question you are asking is about *additional* interactions after the first one, then it seems to me that introducing data about people with no interactions would be irrelevant. My concerns are primarily that (1) the number of previous interactions $X$ is random, so you have a logistic regression analog of an errors-in-variables problem (or maybe a mixed generalized linear model) and (2) it's unlikely the relationship between $X$ and the DV will be linear in the model: it would be worthwhile to consider re-expressing $X$ and checking goodness of fit afterwards.

Comment: (3) Another concern is that your data may have strong interdependencies: if you have the record of all $k$ interactions between a given individual and the government, do you then include $k-1$ cases in the regression corresponding to the state after each interaction? If so, the standard logistic regression model is likely a poor one.

Comment: Great answers. Thanks for the thoughtful response. It's not my study, I'm assessing someone else's. It just struck me as odd to talk about the effect of something without including the comparison of people who had no experience with X. It may not be the number of times something happened that creates the effect, but rather that it happened at all. you may detect an intensification of the effect with more of X, but without zero, do you know if it would hold if there was no X. And, yes, there are many other issues, as it's apparent the number of previous X is definitely not random. Thanks again

Comment: Chris, if you edit your question to include this additional information about the details of the study, you might get some real answers--not just comments--that provide some concrete ways to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine; I am not sure I understand why you think what you say in your last sentence. If no one has no events, then you can't say anything about people with no events, but that doesn't invalidate the rest of the model.